# Restoring default ip rule

Tags: ip, route

I accidentally issued `ip rule flush`, now the default ip rule are all gone, which is,

```
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Anyone know how to add them back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.

```
$ sudo ip rule add priority 32767 lookup default
```